# PostKey gives NulllPointerException. Doesn't create a comment under a certain post node in database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

`Postkey` is a specific post's node saved under one heading "posts". `PostKey = getIntent().getExtras().get("PostKey").toString();` This code works on my `clickpostactivity` which allows the user to click into a post to show the post info such as the image and description on a separate activity.

I am trying to use the `postkey` on my `commentsactivity` now so that a comment's info will save as a node under the `postkey`. I am 100% sure the `postkey` is the issue because as soon as I get rid of it from my code I can enter the `commentsactivity` and write a comment, but without the `postkey` the comment doesn't save as a node under the post itself. Would could I be missing that causes such an error to occur?

Here is my commentsactivity code:

```
private RecyclerView CommentsList;
private ImageButton PostCommentButton;
private EditText CommentInputText;

private DatabaseReference PostsRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private String PostKey, current_user_id;
private String saveCurrentDate;
private String saveCurrentTime;
private String RandomKey;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);

    PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(PostKey).child("Comments");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    PostKey = getIntent().getExtras().get("PostKey").toString();



    CommentsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.comments_list);
    CommentsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    CommentsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    CommentInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_input);
    PostCommentButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.post_comment_button);

    PostCommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ValidateComment();
        }

    });

}



private void ValidateComment() {
    String commentText = CommentInputText.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(commentText)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Write a Comment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());

        Calendar callForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(callForTime.getTime());

        RandomKey = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;

        HashMap commentsMap = new HashMap();
        commentsMap.put("uid", current_user_id);
        commentsMap.put("comment", commentText);
        commentsMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
        commentsMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
        PostsRef.child(current_user_id + RandomKey).updateChildren(commentsMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this, "Comment Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this, "Error Occurred, Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I have used the same method for `clickpostactivity` except I replaced `commentsactivity` with `clickpostactivity`, so the code for this works fine I think.

```
holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent clickPostIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ClickPostActivty.class);
        clickPostIntent.putExtra("PostKey", PostKey);
        startActivity(clickPostIntent);
    }
});

holder.CommentPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent commentIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CommentsActivity.class);
        commentIntent.putExtra("PostKey", PostKey);
        startActivity(commentIntent);
    }
});
```

In the `clickpostactivity` it gets the `postkey` perfectly fine but when trying to even enter the `commentsactivity` the app crashes. Here is the code where it is supposed to get the `postkey` and store the comment data under the specific post's node, instead it gives a `NullPointerException`. Removing the `postkey` from the `postsref` mean the comments are stored in a separate node and show universally across all posts. I want it to save under the specific post node under which the comment was written in.

```
PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(PostKey).child("Comments");

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
PostKey = getIntent().getExtras().get("PostKey").toString();


CommentsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.comments_list);
CommentsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
CommentsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

CommentInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_input);
PostCommentButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.post_comment_button);

PostCommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ValidateComment();

        CommentInputText.setText("");
    }
});

}
private void ValidateComment() {
    String commentText = CommentInputText.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(commentText)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Write a Comment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());

        Calendar callForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(callForTime.getTime());

        RandomKey = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;

        HashMap commentsMap = new HashMap();
        commentsMap.put("uid", current_user_id);
        commentsMap.put("comment", commentText);
        commentsMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
        commentsMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
        PostsRef.child(current_user_id + RandomKey).updateChildren(commentsMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this, "Comment Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this, "Error Occurred, Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Bashir for editing my post, I forgot to highlight some things

Comment: Still have no answer, does anyone have any ideas on how to fix?